# Same shared_ptr for multiple objects?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

### Question

I have 3 classes, `A`, `B`, `C` as following. What is the best way to handle the runtime error? what options we have here? or we have to create one `C` `shared_ptr` for `A`/`B` each;

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class C {};

class A {
public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<C> c) : c_(std::move(c)) {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<C> c_;
};

class B {
public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<C> c) : c_(std::move(c)) {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<C> c_;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<C> c = std::make_shared<C>();
    A a(std::move(c));
    B b(std::move(c)); // This would cause a runtime error, since c is null after being moved to a.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If your want to keep using `c`, then don't `std::move()` it.

Comment: Using `shared_ptr` and then moving them makes little sense. This is something you have to do with `unique_ptr` but the whole point of `shared_ptr` is sharing ownership.

Comment: The code shown does not cause a runtime error. It is safe to move from a `shared_ptr` that has already been moved from.

Comment: Move-constructing a shared pointer just results in the pointer being moved from becoming empty. You can move from the empty pointer. The code you've shown does not result any issues (no runtime error, no undefined behaviour, not even implementation defined behavour).

Comment: this code snippet is coming from chatgpt :(. 

i am little bit confused because move is transfering the ownership. which means it will actually reset the reference counter every time we move? 

if we move the shared_ptr multiple times, will it mess up the reference counter?

Comment: If a `shared_ptr` is moved, it is supposed to keep the use-count (in the new instance). The `shared_ptr` you moved **from** is usually reset.

Comment: @HuazheYin is anything missing or unclear in my answer below ?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) is to **share ownership**.

If this is what you intend here, you simply need to copy it around and remove all your usages of `std::move`.

This is because `std::shared_ptr` is utilizing the copy-constructor (together with the destructor) to keep track of the use-count of the shared object (allowing to release it when it drops to 0).

**A fixed version:**

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class C {};

class A {
public:
    A(std::shared_ptr<C> c) : c_(c) {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<C> c_;
};

class B {
public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<C> c) : c_(c) {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<C> c_;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<C> c = std::make_shared<C>();
    A a(c);
    B b(c);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo - Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rnbccjhT7)

Comment: thanks for ur reply!

if we do move the shared_ptr multiple times. Will it mess up the counter?

Comment: Why do you want to move it ? In the case in your question it seems unneeded. Anyway `std::shared_ptr` supports move, and it should not mess up the use-count if used properly.

Comment: yeah, in my case. looks like i should not move it. but i am just curious if i do move multiple times. will it cause any issue.

Comment: Maybe you should post a new question with a scenario in which you think it makes sense to use `move`. As I wrote the case in this question is clearly not such case. In any case after you `move` from a `shared_ptr` is does not make much sense to `move` from it again (as it will be in an "empty" state after the first `move`).